# Returned list shows individual NULL dimension

Tags: r, function, return, return-value

I had two arrays: A and B and wanted to return them from a function. I used the list command:

```
list1 <- list(A,B)
return(list1)
```

In the original function, I did this to split the list again:

```
A <- list1[1]
B <- list1[2]
```

This worked nicely, except that in the original function when I tried using A in other math, it told me that the dimensions don't match. Turns out that because I used list, both arrays now have a NULL dimension.
list1 itself has a NULL dimension.

Any ideas as to how I can return two arrays from a function in R and still conserve the dimensions of the arrays?

Thanks.

EDIT 1:
I am making a code for bisecting k means and A => 2x4 array of centroid coordinates and b=> 50x2 array of 0/1 values.
Output of `dput(list1):` (No idea what this means)

```
list(structure(list(A = c(5.25555555555556, 4.71304347826087), 
B = c(3.67037037037037, 3.12173913043478), C = c(1.5037037037037, 
1.41739130434783), D = c(0.288888888888889, 0.191304347826087
)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame"), 
structure(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), .Dim = c(50L, 2L)))
```

Comment: I'm confused. Please provide a minimal example.  If you want a list returned from a function, you can do, for example, `foo <- function(x) { A <- x[1]; B <- x[2]; c(A, B) }; foo(list1)` This will return the exact same list you started with.  The problem is might be in your k-means calculations if you get NULL.  Or you may need to use `[[` instead of `[`

Comment: Yes, [[ worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For lists in R, you need to use the double square bracket operator [[ to get at the content of list elements. Using the single bracket [ returns a list. Here's an example:

```
A <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10)
B <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10)
list1 <- list(A,B)
A_list <- list1[1]
A_vector <- list1[[1]]
is.list(A_list)
dim(A_list)
identical(A, A_vector)
dim(A_vector)
```